# Как установить Background из 3х частей

Tags: html, css

Есть `div` его background должен состоять из 3х частей - top, center, bottom

Фон состоит из картинок, центральная часть должна повторятся.

Схема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка блока:

```
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: url(https://www.nature-guide.info/images/website/promobalk.png), url(https://www.nature-guide.info/images/website/promobalk.png);
  background-position: center top, center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}

.block:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  background: url(http://naturalcrooks.com/rambles/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/NewNaturalCrooksHeaderImage.jpg) center top repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вставьте желаемые картинки и готово

```css
.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.block > div {
  height: 33%;
}
.top {
  background: red;
}
.center {
    background: #e4ff00;
}
.bottom {
  background: #008800;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="center "></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```